# client computer cannot connect to server via RDP after 30 minutes

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a Windows Server 2008. I am accessing the server via RDP. I can connect via RDP if I restart it, but after 15-30 mins without an RDP connection I get the following error:

```
An internal error has occurred.
```

I don't know how to fix this. can you help me please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We had in the past some similar issues and where working with Microsoft in order to solve that. They send us a special pre-hotfix. This hotfix was then released to Windows updates. So are you sure your Windows OS is fully up to date?

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for a RDP connection to hang is unstable connectivity at client side.

*Can you ping the server? Check if the connection is broken (ping serverip -t).

*Are you trying to RDP the server by name or IP? If you can RDP by IP without issues, is a DNS related issue.

*Can you remote the server using another remote application (Like VNC) withour issues? If yes, definetly is a Firewall issue with RDP ports (TCP port 3389 and UDP port 3389).

*Are you using DHCP? If Yes, open CMD and run ipconfig /renew

*Is the Windows Firewall disabled (service)? Check and enable these inbound rules:
File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request - ICMPv4-In)
Remote Desktop (TCP-In)

*Check if the NIC Power Management Options --> Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

*Check the current Power Options on this server.

*Make sure your server is fully patched. Also check the following KB from Microsoft https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2571388